# Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone 13

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner learning Flutter on VSCode and am trying to run the project attached in this github link: https://github.com/londonappbrewery/Clima-Flutter-Completed.git. I keep getting this error: "Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.", and I don't know how to fix it.[Image showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GnAX.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472419/cant-emulate-application-on-iphone

Comment: Don't post the error messages as image.